# Visual Studio Color Themes - Apply only "Text Editor" colors (without the other custom UI colors)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've found a Visual Studio (2019) theme I like within the Visual Studio Color Theme editor, but I really want to import only the fonts and colors for the text editor, and not all of the customizations for the rest of the Visual Studio environment.

It appears there is no native support within the color editor to export only certain theme attributes when copying a theme to modify. Also, when customizing a theme, it is possible to select multiple individual UI elements, but no way to then restore them to default such that the theme only contains the Text Editor changes.

I tried loading the theme that has the desired text editor colors, then Tools->Export Settings and then only select "Fonts and Colors", but now this also exports the UI customizations rather than just the text editor colors. Right now, the only way I can see to do this is to create a new theme from the stock dark theme, then manually copy each text editor color from the desired theme to the new one...I'm really trying to avoid this, as there are literally dozens and dozens of text editor colors and this would take a very long time.

I also tried exporting the theme, editing the .vstheme file and removing everything except the Text Editor colors, but Visual Studio throws an exception upon import--presumably all of the elements are required to be defined with the XML.

Thanks for any ideas you can come up with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to get this figured out in what I believe is the easiest way possible. The update to my question where I exported the .*vstheme* file to modify manually was definitely the right path. Basically, I exported the theme that contained the current environment colors that I want to keep. I also exported the theme with the text editor colors I want to apply. I then simply replaced the 3 sections for text editor color settings in the "old" theme file with the new color settings from the "new" file. (Collapsing the XML code down to the 3rd level helped a LOT, as there are almost 10,000 lines.)

After this, I simply imported the modified file and voila—only the editor colors are applied.